# Which font is used for Navigation Drawer in Google Apps?

Tags: android, google-apps, typography

Which type of Roboto font is used for the Navigation Drawer entries of Google apps like Newsstand? 
And which one for the selected entry?

[image]

Comment: My uneducated guess would be fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed". And make it bold for selected item.

Answer (score 2):

`RobotoLight` (item), `RobotoBold` (item selected) and `RobotoRegular` all caps (small item).

Answer (score 0):

Ya, I would say that @harism is right. It does look a lot like San Serif Condensed.

[10 Best Sans-Serif Web Fonts From Google Fonts Library](http://www.forbes.com/sites/allbusiness/2014/03/06/10-best-sans-serif-web-fonts-from-google-fonts-library/)